# Infinite loop when adding objects in a Binary Search Tree C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to insert an object into a BST, but my program gets stuck in a seemingly infinite loop where it places the object in the right node 50 times and the left side once, and it repeats that infinitely.

```
void insert(const T & x, BinaryNode* & t) const
        {

            if(t == NULL){
                t = new BinaryNode(x, NULL, NULL);
                //cout << "in the if" << endl;
            }
            else if(x.offense.compare(t->element.offense) < 0){
                cout << "left" << endl;
                insert(x, t->left);}
            else if(x.offense.compare(t->element.offense) > 0){
                cout << "right" << endl;
                insert(x, t->right);}
            else if(x.offense.compare(t->element.offense) == 0)
                insert(x, t->right);
            else
                ;//do nothing
        }
```

When I comment out the case for '==' its output seems correct but I know that It'd have to have it for cases where the the comparisons are similar.

Comment: "When I comment out the case for '==' its output seems correct" - wrong. you just prevented the infinite loop. the output cannot be correct, as you haven't inserteded the node.

Comment: my guess is that you adding to NULL creates an infinite loop (t->right will be NULL too) - but it's hard to be sure since you haven't posted full compilable code.

Comment: not that it matters, but you could simplify this considerably. Post-null-check (which is correct) the first else-if can just the single test for `<`, inserting down the left side if true, else insert right. The two additional evals and one additional insertion branch are not needed with what appears to be your intention of always shoving duplicates down the right sub-branch.